# C++ - Can't open file from network path in Windows

Tags: c++, windows

I'm having problems using native C++ to open a file located on a network drive on a Windows box. My code works fine if the file is local, but fails if the file is on a network share. I can read the file from Windows explorer perfectly fine.

```
  ifstream ifs(cFilename);
  if(ifs.is_open())
  {
    // Read file here. (This never works for a network path)
  }
```

I've also tried this:

```
struct stat sb;
if (stat(cFilename, &sb) == 0)
{
  // Read file here. (This never works for a network path)
}
```

My path is formatted correctly (e.g. "\\server\filename.ext"), but I still can't open it. Any ideas?

Comment: First thought, have you checked you have permissions to read the file?

Comment: I can read and write to the file via Windows Explorer. Does my application need any specific permissions?

Comment: No, it doesn't, unless this application is a service, which lead me to my second thought, is this a service a console or a desktop app?

Answer (score 2):

If the name is in the form `\\server\filename`, then it seems that might not be correct.  I believe that typically it needs a share name as well:

```
\\server\share\filename
```

Also, make sure that in the code, you escape the backslashes (e.g., `\\\\server\\share\\filename`).

Comment: \\\\server\\share\\filename

Comment: Thanks! I typed them that way and forgot to back quote it ... And then didn't even look at the results. Bad me.

Comment: Yes, I'm adding the extra slashes. I have permissions to read and write to the file through Windows Explorer. Does my application need any specific permissions?

Comment: Did you include the share name?

Comment: Yup, the name of the share is there, and I've given read/write permissions to "everyone"

Comment: You should be able to check error information to find out what the actual failure is.  If that does not work, perhaps edit the question and show a small and complete example that demonstrates the problem.